# Put a Fb Test User as an admin of a page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to make an app that publish on a page.
In order to get access token, i must create a test user that got manage_page permission. I've done it, but in order to get an access_token, this test user must be an admin of the page.
BUT no way to get him as an admin, as he must at least like the page or be a friend of mine(who created the page), and the test user doesn't have permission to have real friends, nor like pages. So how can I make it publish on pages?

Comment: Test users can not interact with real pages. You can log in a the test user, and then create a page. Or you simply use real accounts for testing.

Comment: thanks @CBroe .
Finally I had to log a test user & create a page by him to have access to a page.
Does it means that if I want to have an app that publish to it's app page I'll have to auto log in the app a 'dummy' user that is admin of this page in order to publish something on the app page?

Comment: No, you just need to store the page access token somewhere. (Extend it, then it doesn’t expire by default any more.)